# got trouble with bash files

Tags: bash, macos

I have been trying to install larval, I had updated openssl , installed composer and downloaded larval, final step was to change sth in .bash_profile file and I am pretty sure I did it wrong, and now every command I type in terminal I get the error:

```
 -bash openssl: not found
```

or

```
-bash: composer: not found
```

I am sure the problem is with my bash file but I have no idea what should I do about it

Comment: Did you set PATH in your `.bash_profile`?

Comment: ok, now share your bash profile or we can't do anything...

Comment: You've got a messed up `PATH` environment variable. Make sure you have `PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)` in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: guys I am a beginner on mac terminal and I have no idea what have i done, or even how can i reach my bash file on my mac

Comment: i don't have access to my bash file, when i command : touch .bash_profile , I get the error again

Comment: Try `/bin/cat ~/.bash_profile`